# Rails 3 + Compass + Blueprint not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, blueprint-css, compass-sass

I have used vanilla Blueprint with Rails and it work very well. But when I try using it through compass, it (grid system) somehow does not work.

Here are the steps I am following:

compass init rails

When I go and create the template:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Test Project
    = stylesheet_link_tag :all
    = javascript_include_tag :defaults
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'screen.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'print.css', :media => 'print'
    /[if lt IE 8]
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
    = csrf_meta_tag
  %body
    .container
      .span-24
        The header
      .span-4
        The first column
      .span-16
        The center column
      .span-4.last
        The last column
      .span-24
        The footer
```

It all comes as plain unlike blueprint. I Googled and came across some tutorials/blogs and followed then and it still don't work. Some variations of above which I tried are:

```
compass init rails --using blueprint
compass init rails . --using blueprint
compass init rails . --using blueprint/semantic
```

Then on one of tutorial I found that, body.bp would work, like:

```
  %body.bp
    #container
```

It did changed the formatting a little, but grid is still not working. Please help.

Comment: I tried by removing haml-rails gem and keeping to the minimum set of gems. Even tried with passenger. Still no luck. I must be missing something obvious. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to do it.

%body.bp.two-col

Comment: I have since then completed one design with three columns by extending the provided two-col layout. Compass is really cool!